# Find bash command return value type

Tags: bash

What is the type of the returned value of the `find` command? I'm receiving 2 files and I'm trying to detect if the return is array or not, but the check fails.

I only want to use the first line of the returned value, and tried to do that by detecting if it's array using:

```
local files=`find . -name *.png`

if [[ "$(declare -p $files 2>/dev/null)" =~ "declare -a" ]]; then
    $files=$files[0]
fi
```

Comment: Are you asking about the _output_ of the command or the _exit status_?

Comment: Obviously the output

Comment: _Obviously_ the output is a string :^)

Comment: Oh, really? :( God I hate bash.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to explain what you're trying to do - why do you want an array anyway?

Comment: I'm trying to understand bash, which I personally find very very very far away from any real programming languages, or what it's called. I don't want an array, it gives me an array, I only want the first path.

Comment: `bash` is a real programming language, but it is not a general-purpose programming language. Its purpose is to facilitate combining other programs into one bigger program.

Comment: I know, but it's very different than any other programming language even at declaring a simple variable. Well, we deviate, how can I make sure a `find` command only returns one path? Being a string and not an array, I guess it returns 2 paths separated by a new line.

Comment: Instead of whining at Bash not being such and being such, explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, Sorry. I admit I'm very frustrated about the useless complexity of it.

Comment: The complexity is useful. Maybe think about whom you want to alienate.

Comment: BTW, the answer you accepted shows how to store the output from `find` in a string variable, not an array. If what you actually want is an array, this may not be ideal.

Comment: No, it's not. From a doc, I want to know the input, the output, errors and description. Not clearly stating that it returns a string is bad for a newbie.

Comment: The SO hate, on the other hand, is not useful. Thank you all for the downvotes.

Comment: The whole concept of "returns a string" is inaccurate in this context.

Comment: The only thing a command "returns" is its exit status. Content, as opposed to return value, is written to its standard output, which is how *all* UNIX commands emit their output.

Comment: Because **all** UNIX commands emit their output that same way, by writing that output to a file descriptor, having each command document that it "returns a string"... doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I got it, great explanation @CharlesDuffy, thank you!

Comment: Glad that helps! I've tried to extend my answer to be at least as clear as the comments here; feedback on whether I've been successful in that would be appreciated.

Comment: Knowing that my initial question was misleading and I updated it to reflect the currently accepted solution (and my initial need), I can't accept it. Nonetheless, it's very exhaustive and complete, and I hope it will help others like it helped me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that `find` prints at most one result, you can do this:

```
find /path/to/dir -name 'name_pattern' -print -quit
```

The actions are executed in turn, so the first match (if any) is printed and then the program exits.

To save the output in a variable, you can use `var=$(find ...)`. Note: `var` may be empty if no files match.

Answer (score 4):

No shell commands return arrays -- or strings, for that matter.

The conventional way for a UNIX command to communicate with other processes follows:

- Command-line arguments and environment variables are made available at startup time to specify behavior.
- Input is read from file descriptor #0, "stdin"
- Output is written to file descriptor #1, "stdout"
- Logging and messages for human consumption are written to file descriptor #2, "stderr"
- When the command finishes, it terminates with an integer "exit status" indicating whether it was successful. This is what that command can be said to "return".

In terms of the output from `find`, this is written to file descriptor #1 by convention. How you capture that content -- storing it in an array or a string variable, or just dumping it to the terminal -- is up to you.

Some commands built into the shell, such as `mapfile` or `read -a` can create arrays as side effects, but these are side effects rather than return values.

To safely read a list of files returned by `find` into an array in bash (POSIX sh has no arrays, so this can't be used in scripts that start with `#!/bin/sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  arr+=( "$filename" )
done < <(find . -name '*.png' -type f -print0)
```

Thereafter, you can expand the array with `"${arr[@]}"`: `for file in "${arr[@]}"; do ...`, or `printf -- '- %q\n' "${arr[@]}"` are two examples of this.

Similarly, you can simply refer to `"$arr"` (or `"${arr[0]}"`) for the first element in the array, or to `"${#arr[@]}"` to get the array's length.

Comment: Guys living in the future (Bash 4.4 to be released very soon) will be happy to use `mapfile -t -d '' arr < <(find . -name '*.png' -type f -print0)`, with the usual caveat that `-print0` is not standard.